# Write efficiency difference between Update, Set, and Set with merge

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

Cloud Firestore has this limit:
"Maximum writes per second per database of 10,000 (up to **10 MiB** per second)"
https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas

I was wondering how the **10 MiB** per second limit works.

Let's say I have a document `doc` that is **100 KB**
And I run a transaction in which I only want to update **1 KB** of the `doc`

1. Using `update` (passing the entire object)

```
doc.foo.bar = calculateNewBar(doc.foo.bar)
t.update(docRef, doc);
```

2. Using `update` (targeting specific field)

```
t.update(docRef, {
  "doc.foo.bar": calculateNewBar(doc.foo.bar),
});
```

3. Using `set` (passing the entire object)

```
doc.foo.bar = calculateNewBar(doc.foo.bar)
t.set(docRef, doc);
```

4. Using `set` (with merge)

```
t.set(docRef, {
  doc: { foo: { bar: calculateNewBar(doc.foo.bar) } },
}, {
  merge: true,
});
```

Which way would be the most efficient?
Does Cloud Firestore smartly calculate the diff in all 4 cases above and only write **1 KB**?
Or would 1 and 3 write the entire **100 KB**, and 2 and 4 write **1 KB**?

Comment: For this question, I suggest posting to the Firestore discussion group to get more eyeballs from Firestore staff. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-cloud-firestore-discuss

Comment: Thanks @DougStevenson, I'll do that!